# Heroku push rejected - rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I can't figure out why I keep getting this error. I've tried modifying the buildpack, Gemfile, and database.yml, but keep getting the same message:

```
Counting objects: 563, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (535/535), done.
Writing objects: 100% (563/563), 129.15 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 563 (delta 263), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Failed to detect app matching no buildpack
remote:        More info: https:#
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to #.
remote: 
To https:#
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://#'
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the ruby version on top of your Gemfile?
    ruby '2.2.4'

Comment: adding ruby version is optional

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't set a buildpack when creating your Heroku app. According to the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#setting-a-buildpack-on-an-application) you can manually set this with

`heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by **Inistalizing** and commiting to git again and then deploying the rails app using `heroku create`

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I also had to heroku run rake db:migrate after the new create.

Comment: glad to help @B.Smith!